# Why the publishing is taking too long in Glassfish?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jpa, jsf-2, jpa-2.0

I have a project in Eclipse Indigo with JSF 2 and JPA.
When the Glassfish runs my project and I update my code in the java classes and I  saved the changes, the publishing from glassfish is taking too long.
Something about 20 seconds. And this is not productivity. (Actually is pretty annoying).

I have another project which takes some seconds only, <3 seconds to make the new deploy automatically, with the same operation explained before.

What could take too many time to re-deploy the new changes ? The only difference about these two projects is that the 1st project has more EJB instanciations, that's all.

Could be this ? I'm out of ideas how to solve this problem.
I could post some printscreen about my setting in the project, but I will wait for you guys ask about them to be more concise the information.

Any idea is very welcome.

**EDIT:**
This is [what appear](http://pastebin.com/6N66wY0P) when I just edit one line and save the change:
This is the [log file generated](http://bayfiles.com/file/6jDH/CmQUW3/server.log).

There's something wrong here, isn't it ?

Comment: It's pretty hard for us to guess the cause, I'd suggest to change logging levels in `${domain}/config/logging.properties` to see what exactly is taking so long to deploy.

Comment: I made the changes in the logging.properties as you suggested.
Could you please take a look now ?

Comment: How big are the two jars? How many EJBs in each? For JPA do you list your persistent classes in your persistence.xml?

Answer (score 2):

I had this very same issue.

I'm not exactly sure your problem was the same as mine, but I found that in my case the cause of the problem was that I configured my persistence unit to drop and create the database.  This would be done every time I published.  By turning this off, the problem went away.

In my persistence.xml I had the following:

```
<properties>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
</properties>
```

I changed it to this:

```
<properties>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
</properties>
```

Explanation of the configuration can be found here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DDL

I hope this works for you too ;-)

Comment: @Will I've applied the given feedback. I hope the answer is a bit clearer now. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, now that's an answer!